# Bitwise Command Make bad access error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm coding an application to hide an image information into another image! I do that by removing 4 low level bits from the first image and adding 4 high level bits from second image!
Here is my code:

```
    CGImageRef publicImage = _publicImageView.image.CGImage;
CFDataRef thePublicData;
thePublicData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(publicImage));
UInt8 *publicPixelData = (UInt8 *) CFDataGetBytePtr(thePublicData);
int publicDataLength = CFDataGetLength(thePublicData);

//__________________________________________________________________________

CGImageRef secretImage = _secretImageView.image.CGImage;
CFDataRef theSecretData;
theSecretData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(secretImage));
UInt8 *secretPixelData = (UInt8 *) CFDataGetBytePtr(theSecretData);
int secretDataLength = CFDataGetLength(theSecretData);


int red = 0;
int green = 1;
int blue = 2;

for (int index = 0 ; index < publicDataLength && index < secretDataLength; index +=4) {

    uint pRed = publicPixelData [index + red] % 0x10;
    publicPixelData [index + red] -= pRed;

    uint sRed = secretPixelData [index + red] / 0x10;
    publicPixelData[index + red] += sRed;

    uint pGreen = publicPixelData [index + green] % 0x10;
    publicPixelData [index + green] -= pGreen;

    uint sGreen = secretPixelData [index + green] / 0x10;
    publicPixelData[index + green] += sGreen;

    uint pBlue = publicPixelData [index + blue] % 0x10;
    publicPixelData [index + blue] -= pBlue;

    uint sBlue = secretPixelData [index + blue] / 0x10;
    publicPixelData[index + blue] += sBlue;

}

CGContextRef context;
context = CGBitmapContextCreate(publicPixelData,
                                CGImageGetWidth(publicImage),
                                CGImageGetHeight(publicImage),
                                8,
                                CGImageGetBytesPerRow(publicImage),
                                CGImageGetColorSpace(publicImage),
                                kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

CGImageRef newCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newCGImage];

CGContextRelease(context);
CFRelease(thePublicData);
CGImageRelease(newCGImage);

_hideEffectImageView.image = newImage;
```

To recover Second image, I shift the bits of "__hideEffectImageView" data to high level place!

Here is this code:

```
    CGImageRef stganoImage = _hideEffectImageView.image.CGImage;
CFDataRef stganoData;
stganoData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(stganoImage));
UInt8 *steganoPixelData = (UInt8 *) CFDataGetBytePtr(stganoData);
int publicDataLength = CFDataGetLength(stganoData);



   //__________________________________________________________________________
 //   CGImageRef secretImage;
 //   CFDataRef   theSecretData;
 //   UInt8 *secretPixelData = (UInt8 *)CFDataGetBytePtr(stganoData);

    int red = 0;
    int green = 1;
    int blue = 2;


    for (int index = 0 ; index < publicDataLength; index +=4) {

        steganoPixelData [index + red] = steganoPixelData [index + red] << 0x4 ;
        steganoPixelData [index + green] = steganoPixelData [index + red] << 0x4 ;       
        steganoPixelData [index + blue] = steganoPixelData [index + red] << 0x4 ;
    }

    CGContextRef context;
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate(steganoPixelData,
                                    CGImageGetWidth(stganoImage),
                                    CGImageGetHeight(stganoImage),
                                    8,
                                    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(stganoImage),
                                    CGImageGetColorSpace(stganoImage),
                                    kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    CGImageRef newCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newCGImage];

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CFRelease(stganoData);
    CGImageRelease(newCGImage);

    _recoverSecretImage.image = newImage;
```

In some images I get the "EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code = 2" and Address ...) in the line with code "steganoPixelData [index + red] = steganoPixelData [index + red] << 0x4 ;"

I need to know Why this error appears in some of images and how can I fix it.

So thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Something in this is probably nil. There is most possible explanation. Please log out to the console your `steganoPixelData`. I'm pretty sure that can be nil, because your operation is allowed and you've got only one data structure in this equation: `steganoPixelData[index + red] <<= 0x4`

Maybe your image is nil? Check that. Something is probably deallocated.

Comment: I log data in console and none of them are nil, in one of my log the steganoPixelData is 82, the shift data works correct and (I separated instruction) the assignment data get error...